# paper.js Racing Track

Tags: javascript, html, path, racing

I want to make a graphical output for my racing simulations, so I have found paper.js.

With this code, I can draw each car on a specific course. But I have no idea how I can change every round the speed: speed_car1, speed_car2, speed_car3. So I want to change every round the speed of each car.

Here is my [example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/1ZXfS8MwEMf/lVCQtTJKfziVDR9E8MkH0UcViel1DctyI802VPa/e8m6rTKtL9uDhdDm7pP79r5N6Geg+RSCYfA4ASuqoB8ILNx8wQ0T3KTsimlYsseKzyB+AGG5HisIP5/Ns2Z0lQanQ/aU9Fny0t8ELVIopdhgFyulUjeo0AxZz0DRc/FVNHI3Nxq97Ch6b2oObUHWUsyPovgOSuHypybrGUDx2libxsloL5H5RLafyH1i8K1cIfkYNVdNF/cotQ0XEpZxLT8gihXosa2+LZlxW21wegzX7+eicW0NTsA3QQT5xsWkt0vzogh3KufUfponUfQbkCaOSDqIzBGDLuCSgPMOID8j4KIDGDiJrEvj7IKIPPurkU7iBy/qKeLWXTfcN49R3xo6ceRuOdfCStQhLEDbiG03nPtGWJY1WKJ8MhY415adtjbPqE0rFIR61THYOxTcFb62YVPmZJ1b74Vou1SWLKSlLWm/tStZxzOspatBZYmgKTU52qMMWt6i3Mlxb+sP0JZe+UPQGJAdyoDsnxqQH8qA/D8a4Ab9Y94M8ImvWAfDp5fVFw==):

```
var car1 = new Shape.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [10, 5],
    fillColor: 'red'
});

var car2 = new Shape.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [10, 5],
    fillColor: 'blue'
});

var car3 = new Shape.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [10, 5],
    fillColor: 'yellow'
});

var speed_car1 = 1.0;
var speed_car2 = 1.2;
var speed_car3 = 1.5;

var diagonal = new Point(view.size).length;

var path = new Path();
path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.add(new Point(60, 130));
path.add(new Point(100, 100));
path.add(new Point(200, 50));
path.add(new Point(280, 60));
path.add(new Point(340, 70));
path.add(new Point(500, 250));
path.add(new Point(470, 320));
path.add(new Point(100, 320));
path.add(new Point(60, 130));
path.smooth();

car1.onFrame = function(event) {
    var offset = event.count * speed_car1;
    var loc = path.getLocationAt(offset % path.length);
    if (loc) {
        this.position = loc.point;
        this.rotation = loc.tangent.angle;
    }
}
car2.onFrame = function(event) {
    var offset = event.count * speed_car2;
    var loc = path.getLocationAt(offset % path.length);
    if (loc) {
        this.position = loc.point;
        this.rotation = loc.tangent.angle;
    }
}
car3.onFrame = function(event) {
    var offset = event.count * speed_car3;
    var loc = path.getLocationAt(offset % path.length);
    if (loc) {
        this.position = loc.point;
        this.rotation = loc.tangent.angle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use similar calculation to the one you're using to determine location:

```html
var car1 = new Shape.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [10, 5],
    fillColor: 'red'
});

var car2 = new Shape.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [10, 5],
    fillColor: 'blue'
});
 
var car3 = new Shape.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [10, 5],
    fillColor: 'yellow'
});

var speed_car1 = 1.0;
var speed_car2 = 1.2;
var speed_car3 = 1.5;

var diagonal = new Point(view.size).length;

var path = new Path();
path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.add(new Point(60, 130));
path.add(new Point(100, 100));
path.add(new Point(200, 50));
path.add(new Point(280, 60));
path.add(new Point(340, 70));
path.add(new Point(500, 250));
path.add(new Point(470, 320));
path.add(new Point(100, 320));
path.add(new Point(60, 130));
path.smooth();

car1.onFrame = function(event) {
    var offset = event.count * speed_car1;
    var loc = path.getLocationAt(offset % path.length);
    if (loc) {
        this.position = loc.point;
        this.rotation = loc.tangent.angle;
    }
}
car2.onFrame = function(event) {
    var offset = event.count * speed_car2;
    var loc = path.getLocationAt(offset % path.length);
    if (loc) {
        this.position = loc.point;
        this.rotation = loc.tangent.angle;
    }
}
car3.onFrame = function(event) {
    var offset = event.count * speed_car3;
    var loc = path.getLocationAt(offset % path.length);
    if (loc) {
        this.position = loc.point;
        this.rotation = loc.tangent.angle;
    }
    // compare offset with some epsilon
    if ((offset % path.length) < 1) {
      // adjust speed
      speed_car3 = speed_car3 *2 };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have one problem. If I use a array there is a bug. Sometimes the car is slightly set back. In this example the car is slightly set back on lap 3:  goo.gl/Q0ED6Y (Short Link because I cant write the full link in the comments :( )

Comment: Ok i have found my problem ;) (event.count is the problem. I made a new variable for that. Every onFrame i add +1 and if the car pass the start then i set it to 0. So the problem is gone. Thanks a lot for your help ;)